# How to get a list of last N system calls on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, system-calls

I need a way to get from kernel few last system calls that occurred.
Does kernel keep such log?

This should be possible, but it might be more complicated than worth it.

Any ideas are welcome. Programming language doesn't really matter. Also an idea from any Unix should do as it would probably be possible to apply it to Mac OS X.

Edit:

Some minutes ago I found the dtruss built-in shell script that actually does what I need, but I'd like to do this directly from Python or some other programming language that I can call from Python.

I think piping to dtruss will not be efficient enough. Does anyone know whether a source code for dtruss exists somewhere? Or at least of strace, which, if I got it right, does the same on Linux?

Answer (score 2):

dtruss is part of dtrace, and that is available from [Apple open source](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/dtrace). HTH

Comment: Yes, I discovered this and that dtrace is opensource too. Upvote anyway. I am going to dig further. Let see if someone comes up with the solution before me and optionally with better one. :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `history` command to get all the commands entered from the last terminal restart.

You can use it with `history | grep ssh` to get all commands entered with `ssh`

Comment: history command returns only shell history, not system calls to OS kernel from other applications. But I found dtruss command that does that and I'll edit my Q now.